# Sizeof next byte in byte array

Tags: c, arrays, byte

I have an unsigned char and I add integers to it but I want to get the `sizeof` next byte (i.e `sizeof` `unsigned short int` or `unsigned int` and so on).

The following code demonstrates what I want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void write_ushort(unsigned char *b, unsigned short int value) { b[1] = value >> 8; b[0] = value; }
static void write_ulong(unsigned char *b, unsigned long int value) { write_ushort(b + 2, value >> 16); write_ushort(b, value); }

static unsigned short int read_ushort(const unsigned char *b) { return b[1] << 8 | b[0]; }
static unsigned long int read_ulong(const unsigned char *b) { return read_ushort(b + 2) <<16 | read_ushort(b); }

int main() {
     unsigned char b[2];
     unsigned int v0;       /* 4 */
     unsigned short int v1; /* 2 */

     v0 = 200; v1 = 1235;
     write_ushort(&b[0], v0); write_ulong(&b[1], v1);

     /* what i expect printf to output is:
      * 4 2 
      * but it obviously outputs 1 1 */
     printf("%d %d\n", read_ushort(&b[0]), read_ulong(&b[1]));
     printf("%d %d\n", (int)sizeof(b[0]), (int)sizeof(b[1]));
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side Note: Neither 256 nor 512 is gonna fit into an `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Mysticial oh yes, you're right... i'll update the question. thank you

Comment: `b[0]` and `b[1]` are both `unsigned char`... when you assign to them, the rvalues (`v0`, `v1`) are treated as `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible. The `sizeof` operator will return the size of a type, or the size of the declared type of a variable. You can't massage anything else out of it, and your code won't keep track of what type of variable a number was stored in before you assigned it to a new variable.

Regardless of the type of `v0` or `v1`, when they're stored in elements of your array, they are converted to `unsigned char`.

If you want `4 2` as output, you'll need to pass `sizeof(v0)` and `sizeof(v1)` to `printf`, or keep track of this some other way.

Answer (score 2):

C is statically typed, and you can't just change the data type of a variable (or array) by assigning something to it. In fact you can't change the data type of a variable at all: a variable corresponds (almost exactly) to a certain chunk of memory with its size defined at compile time. You can cast variables so that they are treated as though they were a different type for a specific operation, but the chunk of memory is the same size always.

---

And, since a variable is just a block of memory there is no way for the computer (or compiler) to know that you are using a `char[2]` array to store a `short` or a `long`. You have to keep track of this yourself.

Comment: Your question still looks like you expect `sizeof(b[0])` and `sizeof(b[1])` to somehow change. They won't. `sizeof(whatever)` is a _compile time constant_ and therefore unrelated to the _value_ of any variable (and `sizeof(b[0])` and `sizeof(b[1])` will always be the same anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a major problem:

```
write_ulong(&b[1], v1);
```

You take the second byte (of a two-byte array) and pass it to `write_ulong` where it's handled as an array of *four* bytes. This means you are writing several bytes beyond the original array `b` and overwrite the stack. This is undefined behavior and will make your program behave very strange.